# How to show the value of a variable? - Android

Tags: java, android, variables, textview, show

I would like to show the value of a variable in a TextView, like the echo in php ..

I'll explain .. I have a variable called "**contadorRegistros**", which stores the number of records of the app .. I want to show in a TextView which the value of it ...

In php I would do it:

```
<php

echo "this is my variable $contadorRegistros"

?>
```

How to do it on android?

And sorry for my english ... I'm brazilian ..

Edit:

I can show a text, using the code:

```
TextView t = (TextView) findViewById (R.id.tvCont);
t.setText ("Test");
```

But when I switch "Test" by the variable I want, it does not work:

```
TextView t = (TextView) findViewById (R.id.tvCont);
t.setText (contadorRegistros);
```

---

What can I do for work? =/

Comment: Have you read [Hello World apllication](http://developer.android.com/resources/tutorials/hello-world.html) from android ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your variable is a int then doing something like this would help,

```
t.setText (contadorRegistros+"");
```

Comment: Funny how a direct answer get's voted up and marked as correct, whereas I tend to give an answer to actually let him do some of the coding himself - to learn - and it get's ignored. Eitherway problem solved! (as one could question what t would be in this code)

Answer (score 1):

You want something like this in you java code:

```
t=new TextView(this);

t=(TextView)findViewById(R.id.TextView1); 
t.setText("I changed the text");
```

the R.id has to be changed the way you named your textview. Furthermore just create a string and add your variable name to the string. Then let the setText show it.

Edit:
see also http://developer.android.com/resources/tutorials/hello-world.html

Answer (score 0):

The number is not showing up because its an integer and setText() method takes String or CharSequence as its arguement.
 So you should first convert the number into a String. Only then you will be able to use it in the setText() method. You can do it like this:

```
   t.setText(Integer.toString(contadorRegistros));
```